# Cannot assign to a parameter

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I have declared a function

```
func someFunction(parameterName: Int) {
    parameterName = 2  //Cannot assign to let value parameter Name
    var a = parameterName
}
```

and trying to assign it a value during runtime, but it gives me error
"Cannot assign to let value parameter Name".

Is the parameter name constant by default? Can I change it to a variable?

Comment: For the minimum headache, you can add the line `var paramterName = parameterName` at the top of your function. The declaration shadows the parameter, which turns `paramaterName` into a `var`.

Answer (score 47):

**[In Swift >= 3.0]** Function parameters are defined as if by `let` and thus are constants.  You'll need a local variable if you intend to modify the parameter.  As such:

```
func someFunction (parameterName:Int) {
  var localParameterName = parameterName
  // Now use localParameterName
  localParameterName = 2;
  var a = localParameterName;
}
```

**[In Swift < 3.0]** Declare the argument with `var` as in:

```
func someFunction(var parameterName:Int) {
  parameterName = 2;
  var a = parameterName;
}
```

use of `inout` has a different semantics.

[Note that "variable parameters" will disappear in a future Swift version.]  Here is the Swift documentation on *"variable parameters"*:

> Function parameters are constants by default. Trying to change the
>   value of a  function parameter from within the body of that function
>   results in a compile-time  error. This means that you can’t change the
>   value of a parameter by mistake.
>
> However, sometimes it is useful for a function to have a variable copy of a  parameter’s value to work with. You can avoid defining a
>   new variable yourself within  the function by specifying one or more
>   parameters as variable parameters instead.  Variable parameters are
>   available as variables rather than as constants, and give a  new
>   modifiable copy of the parameter’s value for your function to work
>   with.
>
> Define variable parameters by prefixing the parameter name with the keyword var: ..."

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.”

If you actually want to change the value stored in a location that is passed into a function, then, as @conner noted, an `inout` parameter is justified.  Here is an example of that [**In Swift >= 3.0**]:

```
  1> var aValue : Int = 1
aValue: Int = 1
  2> func doubleIntoRef (place: inout Int) { place = 2 * place }
  3> doubleIntoRef (&aValue)
  4> aValue
$R0: Int = 2
  5> doubleIntoRef (&aValue) 
  6> aValue 
$R1: Int = 4
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to modify the argument passed in, you have to designate it as an inout parameter:

```
func someFunction(inout parameterName:Int)
{
    parameterName = 2;
    var a = parameterName;
}
```

Note this will change the variable that was passed in as well. If that isn't what you're looking for, use var as GoZoner suggested.

Comment: It is not clear that the OP want's an `inout` parameter vs a `var` parameter. In many languages that pass by value the value or a parameter variable can be changed in the method/function.

Comment: No, this has the side effect that whatever variable is passed in is modified, which is probably not what OP wants.